# Can NLTK's XMLCorpusReader be used on a multi-file corpus?

Tags: python, xml, nltk, nlp

I'm trying to use NLTK to do some work on the [New York Times Annotated Corpus](http://nytnlp.googlegroups.com/web/new_york_times_annotated_corpus.pdf?gda=YSD3XlUAAADIiIQXTaZc7t_Z2e7P-nlf8Jldl4UE6-KChg2Y0XdPoEnDJZHGdnBmEWV8W-XIw5P180hAuqa8U_xChid0w715HJ_FiG1oec6ngyrQwZquuxrtYix3qocOGWUY90Yyf_g) which contains an XML file for each article (in the News Industry Text Format NITF).

I can parse individual documents with no problem like so:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import XMLCorpusReader
reader = XMLCorpusReader('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes/1987/01/01', r'0000000.xml')
```

I need to work on the whole corpus though.
I tried doing this:

```
reader = XMLCorpusReader('corpora/nytimes', r'.*')
```

but this doesn't create a useable reader object. For instance

```
len(reader.words())
```

returns

```
raise TypeError('Expected a single file identifier string')
TypeError: Expected a single file identifier string
```

How do I read this corpus into NLTK?

I'm new to NLTK so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no NLTK expert, so there may be an easier way to do this, but naively I would suggest that you use [Python's `glob` module](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html). It supports Unix-stle pathname pattern expansion.

```
from glob import glob
texts = glob('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes/*')
```

So that would give you the names of the files matching the expression specified, in list-form. 
Then depending on how many of them you want/need to have open at once, you could do:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import XMLCorpusReader
for item_path in texts:
    reader = XMLCorpusReader('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes/', item_path)
```

As suggested by @waffle paradox:, you can also whittle this list of `texts` down to suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution based on machine yearning and waffle paradox's comments.
Build a list of articles using [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) and pass them to XMLCorpusReader as a list:

```
from glob import glob
import re
years = glob('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes_test/*')
year_months = []
for year in years:
    year_months += glob(year+'/*')
    print year_months
days = []
for year_month in year_months:
    days += glob(year_month+'/*')
articles = []
for day in days:
    articles += glob(day+'/*.xml')
file_ids = []
for article in articles:
    file_ids.append(re.sub('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes_test','',article))
reader = XMLCorpusReader('nltk_data/corpora/nytimes_test', articles)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can specify multiple files.  (from: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.xmldocs.XMLCorpusReader-class.html)

The problem here is that I suspect all your files are contained in a file structure along the lines of `corpora/nytimes/year/month/date`.  XMLCorpusReader does not recursively traverse the directories for you.  i.e., with your code above, `XMLCorpusReader('corpora/nytimes', r'.*')`, XMLCorpusReader only sees the xml files in `corpora/nytimes/` (i.e., none, since there are only folders), not in any subfolders that `corpora/nytimes` may contain.  In addition, you probably meant to use `*.xml` as your second parameter.

I would recommend traversing the folders yourself to build absolute paths (the docs above specify that explicit paths for the `fileids` parameter will work), or if you have a list of year/month/date combinations available, to use that to your advantage.

Comment: Thanks Waffle Paradox. That's very helpful.